# Save Leaflet drawn features with attributes to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, leaflet, geojson

**Goal:**

In order to have a fully interactive map, I would like to be able to save some drawn features (in a second step with some attributes that may be grabbed through an input mask form or pop-up) on a Leaflet map to a PostgreSQL (PostGIS) database table.

**Technical details:**

I am using Lighttpd as webserver + geoserver (based on jetty) to serve my base vector layer on which I'd want to write the new features.

**What I have read and tried:**

Based on this code : https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/d30c44b081be31aea483 
it is possible to "export" the features as a GeoJson string to a local file.

Related resources that I've tried but doesn't work:
[Leaflet.draw: add attributes and save to file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211496/leaflet-draw-add-attributes-and-save-to-file)

And with this, I'm able to print out to the console a GeoJSON string that is ready to be written in a database field but I do not know how to technically communicate it to the database:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018630/how-to-save-a-completed-polygon-points-leaflet-draw-to-mysql-table

Related to the Geoserver documentation (the "demo" menu on the left column), it is not possible to write a GeoJson string to the connected PostgreSQL database: WFS-T only allows to write features using the GML format...

I remember (long time ago, so it is blurry in my mind) some functions with OpenLayer that could do some parsing on a GeoJson string to make it "GML ready" but I can not find any equivalent within Leaflet.

Am I stuck or is there an elegant way to store drawn vector features from a Leaflet map into a PostgreSQL database (based, or not, on Geoserver)?
If not possible, which other (light) techniques would be nice to use?

**The raw code example:**
https://pastebin.com/raw/Tbv9AcFs

**Edit:**

The answer given in the thread on which this question was marked as duplicate ( [How to add Geoserver WFS to Leaflet JS Application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/how-to-add-geoserver-wfs-to-leaflet-js-application) ) is to use the Leaflet-WFST plugin: https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST.

When I tried the first command: `npm i leaflet-wfst --save`

I get an error "command not found". So it doesn't work in my really simple case where I use Geoserver. What I would like to find is a small function that converts a geojson object (which I already have!) to a GML one (which is the only format available with Geoserver WFST protocol).

Comment: You can use Leaflet-WFST the same way as you're using Leaflet, i.e., by using unpkg, like this: `https://unpkg.com/leaflet-wfst@2.0.1-beta.18/dist/leaflet-wfst.min.js`